# Why does NCSI show no connection when I eliminate the default route?

Tags: windows-10, networking, routing-table

I'm experimenting with routing tables on my Windows 10 machine, to gain more control of traffic. I've noticed that the NCSI will show no internet when there is.

Specifically, if I eliminate the default route (0.0.0.0/0), then the NCSI displays "No internet", even when I add equivalent routes back into the routing table. For example if add 128.0.0.0/1 and 0.0.0.0/1, both pointing to the same gateway and interface, I would think I've essentially broken the default route into two pieces, one piece for IPs that start with 1 and one piece for IPs that start with 0. This should cover all possible IPs, and indeed, I can connect to any site on the internet. I'm having trouble seeing how this is not functionally equivalent to a single route of 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to the same interface.

Also, I can specifically connect to "http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt" and resolve the name "dns.msftncsi.com" to 131.107.255.255. From what I can gather these are the two tests that NCSI uses to determine connectivity, and yet it still displays "no internet".

What gives?